# Updating MySQL Field Using Volley POST Request With Shared Preferences As Parameter

Tags: php, android, sql, sharedpreferences, android-volley

My app opens with a Login Acitivity where after logging in, the email and password are stored into shared preferences. Then the user is brought to a second activity where they must press a button that "checks" them in , meaning they are available for work.

Using volley, I'm trying to send the email address and the String "available" as parameters to update a field in my SQL database.

So I have a couple constants defined in a separate class:

**Config.java**

```
//Currently logged in employee
public static final String EMAIL_SHARED_PREF = "employee_email";

//URL to PHP file that updates the field
public static final String EMPLOYEE_STATUS_URL = "http://localhost/android/employeestatus.php";
```

I have a method in my activity that makes the POST request to update the SQL field:

**CheckinActivity.java**

```
private void checkin() {

    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences(Config.SHARED_PREF_NAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    final String employee_email = sharedPreferences.getString(Config.EMAIL_SHARED_PREF,"Not Available");
    final String employee_status = "available";

    StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, Config.EMPLOYEE_STATUS_URL,
            new Response.Listener<String>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(String response) {
                    Toast.makeText(CheckinActivity.this, response, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            },
            new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                    Toast.makeText(CheckinActivity.this, error.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            }) {
        @Override
        protected Map<String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError {
            Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<>();
            params.put("employee_status", employee_status);
            params.put("employee_email", employee_email);
            return params;
        }
    };

    RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
    requestQueue.add(stringRequest);

    Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

And finally the PHP file that handles the request:

**employeestatus.php**

```
<?php

 if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='POST'){

 $employee_email = $_POST['employee_email'];
 $employee_status = $_POST['employee_status'];

//importing database connection script
 require_once('dbConnect.php');

 //Creating sql query
 $sql = "UPDATE employees
            SET employee_status = '$employee_status'
          WHERE employee_email = '$employee_email'";

 //Updating database table
 if (mysqli_query($conn,$sql)) {
 echo 'Status Updated';
 }
 else {
 echo 'Status Not Updated';
 }

 //closing connection
 mysqli_close($conn);
 }

{ print_r($_POST); return; }
```

As it is now, **ALL** the column fields update to show available instead of just the employee who is logged into the app. Any ideas?

**EDIT**

My original attempt was obviously wrong, the part where I was trying to post the email address. I only need to update my `employee_status` field but need the shared preference email from the app to be the WHERE in my SQL UPDATE.

I thought I could append the email to the url and assign it as a GET value but that didn't work. Hmmm still working on it...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally got it working! Made many mistakes:

1. I didn't properly get the sharedPreferences email value
2. I had my params backwards in the volley request
3. I incorrectly named my POST values in the php file
4. I forgot some apostrophes in the SQL query

Adding in `{ print_r($_POST); return; }` to the php file really helped out seeing what was being sent, and displaying it in the toast. All the above code is working now.

So now, I plan to make a checkOut method which does the exact opposite when the employee checks out :)

Hopefully someone finds this useful.